# Touch Event not working in FullCalendar v.-3.9?

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-3

I am using **FullCalendar 3.9** version plugin for show Driver events. where click event is working on Desktop view but not in mobile device because on mobile phone touch event works. so how can i bind touch event on calendar and show data.

in **`fullCalendar({})`**  **eventClick**: i am using two method

```
$("#openFancybox").fancybox();
  $("#openFancybox").click();
```

so i want to fire those method on click. but it is not firing.  also i removed all lines of method and just `alert('test')` but it is also not working. no error appearing what is reason i do not know?

[image]

My JS code

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
             eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'yellow');
                url = '{{ route("boking-details", 'XXX') }}'.replace('XXX', calEvent.booking_id);
                $.fancybox.destroy();
                element = '<a id="openFancybox"  data-type="ajax" data-src="' + url + '" href="javascript:;"></a>'
                $(".element").html(element);
                $("#openFancybox").fancybox();
                $("#openFancybox").click();
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                if (confirm("This booking has now been moved."+ " with booking time " + event.start.format() )) {
                    changeBooking(event, delta, revertFunc);

                    //savedrop(event.id,event.start,event.end);    
                } else {
                    $('.popover').popover('hide');
                    revertFunc();
                }
            },

            eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
              $el.popover({
                title: eventObj.title,
                content: eventObj.description,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'top',
                container: 'body'
              });
            },
            timeFormat : "H(:mm)",
            //slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
            displayEventTime: false,
            //  now: '2018-11-07',
            editable: true, // enable draggable events
            dragRevertDuration: 1000,
            aspectRatio: 2.5,
            scrollTime: '10:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            slotLabelInterval: 15,
            header: {
                left: 'today, prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineMonth,timelineWeek,timelineDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
            views: {
                timelineThreeDays: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    duration: {days: 3}
                },
                timelineWeek: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd DD/MM',
                    //titleFormat: '(d MMMM yyyy)'
                    //titleFormat:"HH",
                },
                timelineDay: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    //timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                    slotLabelFormat:"HH",
                }
            },
            resourceLabelText: 'Drivers & Companion',
            events: '{{route("all-driver-calender",["type"=>"bookings"])}}&driver_id='+getDriverIdFromURL(),
            resources:'{{route("all-driver-calender",["type"=>'driverName'])}}&driver_id='+getDriverIdFromURL()
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that fullCalendar's `eventClick` does not work, or that this command: `$("#openFancybox").click()` does not work? Your description is unclear. And if you're not sure which one is the problem, then what have you done to try and debug / narrow down the issue? We cannot execute your code, only you can do that.

Comment: yes u r right..  that is not working.

Comment: Which one? I gave you two options.

Comment: Hi Adyson . i check this issue and it is not working if screen size is blow of **976px** approx on **mobile device** basically on small mobile device. here **eventClick()** function now triggering. so can you help me in this.

Comment: "now triggering"...did you mean "not triggering"?

Comment: i fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by setting . it is working **FullCalendar v-3.9**. now every button working on mobile that screen is very small like 560px (4Inch ,5inch etc).

```
width:800px,
height:600px,
```